# MongoDb 2.0 C# driver not creating values for IDs on inserts

Tags: c#, mongodb

It says here (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators) that the driver should use one of the builtin ID generators to generate a new ID for properties ID, id, _id (convention).

I have a model with

```
public string Id { get;set; }
```

and the automatic ID generation is not happening. Inserted document has an ID of null.

Snippet from my repository code:

```
    public void Save<TEntity>(TEntity item) where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
        collection.InsertOne(item);
    }
```

Comment: please include a verifiable sample code to ensure we all are on same page. For clarification, what is your MongoDB and driver version? Your post title says its 2.0 while reference link is pointing to 2.2

Comment: MongoDB 3.2.6 and Mongo driver 2.2.3

Comment: My code is simple, pretty much simple models with straightforward CRUD code, see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further troubleshooting I got this working.

Had to put attribute [BsonId] set to StringObjectIdGenerator to Id properties.

```
[BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
```

The docs at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators are certainly misleading or not clear enough

> Some of these Id generators are used automatically for commonly used
>   Id types: GuidGenerator is used for a Guid ObjectIdGenerator is used
>   for an ObjectId StringObjectIdGenerator is used for a string
>   represented externally as ObjectId

I've opened an issue with MongoDb JIRA tracker and I'll post their reply here if they provide any insight into that.